# how do I install metapy for a specific version of python

Tags: python

I have Anaconda and Python 2.7 install on my PC. "metapy" is install and works just fine with Anaconda in eclipse. But when i try to run any .py file that contains "import metapy" from windows command line i get this error because i have python 2.7 in windows path:

ImportError: No module named metapy
I do not want to change or add Anaconda to windows path.

I tried to install metapy using pip install metay but i get this message
Requirement already satisfied: metapy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages

Is there any way I can install metapy for the python 2.7?

Comment: Did you create the current anaconda environment for Python 2.7?

Comment: No what is that?

Comment: You might want to read up on the [basics of conda environment management](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)